# PayPal Express Checkout doesn't allow residents of United States

Tags: paypal

From USA, somebody tried to purchase the product from our website but it showing the below error. **We're sorry, PayPal doesn't allow residents of United States to ship purchases to India**. I created two PayPal Accounts with Countries USA and INDIA and tried making payment with both accounts, but I am not getting this issue from different ways of testing (i.e., Providing Billing and Shipping information INDIA/USA viceversa). Is there anybody get this same issue in drupal commerce. Any ideas please..

Answer (score 0):

The buyer is experiencing this because they are trying to ship to a different address outside their own country.

To override this security feature is to edit the 'addressoveride'
parameter in the SetEC api cal; you'll want to do is drill down in
drupal and set to --> addressoveride=1, as well as in the IPN
listener if applicable. Page 24.

You'll also if you can disabled the paypal address confirmed variable. Page 23

[See Doc](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_expresscheckout_advancedfeaturesguide.pdf)

Comment: I noticed that the Billing or Shipping Information Address (USA/INDIA) is not the issue for this error. The PayPal Account created by user is from the country USA then only this error is showing. I checked with PayPal Account created with country India and then it is not showing error. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: That is correct J. Sinha. United States shipping/billing address' can only reside in the country there in and ship within this country, however for other countries this is NOT the case. The reason why is there are strict sanctions in the U.S vs. International countries. This is why you are experiencing an error form the US account and NOT the India account. This is only when implementing a paypal checkout. You can return them to a review page before the DOEC api is done to change the shipping to international

Answer (score 0):

As of Now.. this issue is resolved. I am totally Commented Shipping Information in Commerce Paypal Module. i.e., In the file, "commerce_paypal/modules/ec/commerce_paypal_ec.module".

i.e., I commented code from,

```
if (module_exists('commerce_shipping')) {
// If we have a shipping address, pass it to PayPal ... 
... //some default code here...
} 
else { 
... //some default code here...
 }
```

It may be useful for anybody who have this issue.